# WM messages from PowerPoint clicker

Tags: windows, message, wndproc

I'm trying to find a WM message(s) that are sent to PowerPoint-like applications when prev/next button on clickers (i.e. [this](http://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/432/5873)) is pressed. Anybody knows what are these? It seems to be basically 4: prev, next, black screen, start presentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody needs exact messages (wParam of WM_KEY*):

```
VK_PRIOR/VK_NEXT (PgUp/Down) (prev/next slide)
VK_F5 (F5) (start presentation)
VK_OEM_PERIOD (.) (blank)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe they just map to the corresponding key presses (does on OSX)

Prev/next = left/right arrows
Start = F5
Black = B

Comment: You're right, although the messages are little bit different (maybe just because of Windows). I was using wrong handle to catch messages and that confused me.